# Wordpress query with multiple variable post IDs

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, wordpress

I'm trying to create a custom wordpress query that pulls 3 specific IDs based on 3 different variables that are set using Elliot Condon's brilliant advanced custom fields.

I'm using this to set my variables:

```
<?php
    $post1 = get_field('post_1');
    $post2 = get_field('post_2');
    $post3 = get_field('post_3');
?>
```

And I want to pass those variables to a custom query like this:

```
<?php
    $post_list = array($post1, $post2, $post3);
    foreach( $post_list as $post_id ) :
        query_posts('p='.$post_id);
        while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        // echo the post
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_query();
    endforeach;
?>
```

However, the above doesn't seem to work and results in a broken page. Anyone have any ideas of how to fix? I'm obviously passing the variables into the query wrong, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

**EDIT - SOLUTION**

Here's the working updated block. Big thanks to DACrosby! I'm running the query for a custom post type, so I needed to specify which type in the `$args`.

```
<div class="row">
    <?php
    $post1 = get_field('related_1');
    $post2 = get_field('related_2');
    $post3 = get_field('related_3');
    $args = array(
        'post__in' => array( $post1, $post2, $post3 ),
        'post_type' => 'work'
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    ?>
    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
    <ul class="case-studies cf fade-in fade-in-3">
        <!-- Basic Projects -->
        <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <?php
                //Get Featured Image URL
                $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
                //Get Project Categories
                $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'type' );
            ?>
            <li class="case-study">
                <img src="<?php echo $feat_image; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="cs-hover">
                    <div class="col-table cs-text">
                        <div class="col-tcell">
                            <span><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                            <span class="divider"></span>
                            <span><?php the_field('description'); ?></span>
                            <?php if(get_field('services')): ?>
                                <ul class="tags">
                                    <?php while(has_sub_field('services')): ?>
                                        <li><?php the_sub_field('service'); ?></li>
                                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                                </ul>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <span class="text-link">View Project</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)

> **Caveats** query_posts() is only one way amongst many to query the database and generate a list of posts. Before deciding to use query_posts(), be sure to understand the drawbacks.
>
> **Alters Main Loop** query_posts() is meant for altering the main loop. ...
>
> **Secondary Loops** To create secondary listings (for example, a list of related posts at the bottom of the page, or a list of links in a sidebar widget), try making a new instance of WP_Query or use get_posts().

[An example of WP_Query usage:](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

```
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
  echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

From there you'll just modify the $args sent to WP_Query. For example:

```
$args = array(
         'post__in' => array( $post1, $post2, $post3 ),
         'post_type' => 'desired_post_type'
);
```

Comment: I tried implementing that, but still can't get it to work. I added my full code block to above... maybe you can spot where I'm going wrong? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I don't just see anything immediately wrong.. Are you getting any errors? Check the error_log file on your server, or [display errors through WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)

Comment: Not getting any errors in the log, and the rest of the page is loading just fine. All that's being outputted though is `<div class="row">" "</div>`

Comment: Verify what get_field is returning. I use ACF alot and by default it returns a post object - for this setup you'd want it to return the object ID. It's a setting in the Custom Fields setup section per custom field.  What's the output of `var_dump($args);`?

Comment: Yeah, I have it set to return the ID. Here's the results of the var_dump: `array(1) { ["post__in"]=> array(3) { [0]=> int(84) [1]=> int(92) [2]=> int(104) } }`

Comment: Ahhh, figured it out! Was just missing the `'post_type' => 'type'` argument since it's a custom post type. I'll update the code above with the solution.

Comment: Perfect, glad you got it! I'll update my answer as well.